# Difference between $var = <FH> and $_ in Perl

Tags: perl

Recently I came across something like this in a certain perl script:

```
while(<FH>){
    $var1 = <FH>; $var2 = $_
}
```

Since the diamond operator with file handle name inside works the same way as `readline(FH)`; may I know are there any special meaning in writing like this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It may make sense for processing some more complicated **sequences**  of lines from the file.  It is a nere guess without more complete example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's reach for the documentation for the direct question.

From [readline](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html)

> This is the internal function implementing the `<EXPR>` operator, but you can use it directly. The `<EXPR>` operator is discussed in more detail in [I/O Operators in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators)

and in the [I/O Operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators) we find the statement

> `<FILEHANDLE>` may also be spelled `readline(*FILEHANDLE)`. See [readline](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html).

Thus `<FH>` and `readline(FH)` are equivalent (we can pass `*FH` or `FH` to `readline()`).

Note that *lexical filehandles* are preferred to typeglobs. See [Typeglobs and Filehandles in perldata](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles) for instance. So open your files like

```
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
```

and then you do `<$fh>` to read "from the filehandle" (from the file associated with it).

The operator `<>` itself has a few other properties, though.  See the extensive `perlop` discussion.

---

The rest of the code snippet in the question brings up other issues.

The `<FH>` inside the `while` condition is in the scalar context so it reads one line from the resource connected to `FH`. As we enter the loop body, the `<FH>` will *again* read a line, thus the next one, which is assigned to `$var1`.

When `<$FH>` is the sole thing inside the `while` conditional then the line gets assigned to the default [variable `$_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables).  See `I/O Operators` linked above.  So `$var2` gets assigned this line.

Thus after the body of the loop executed, we have the first line in `$var2` and the next line in `$var1`. This strange loop goes over two lines in each iteration, assigning first the second line of the two, and then the first one.